# Debian installer does not recognize the unallocated space

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot, debian-installer, asus

I am trying to install Debian 12.4.0 alongside Windows 10 in my Asus Zenbook Flip 15 (UX564). Despite having prepared 100 GB of free space for Debian installation (see first picture), the Debian installer fails to detect this unallocated space when I do the guided partitioning by using the largest continous free space (see second picture).

[image: Current disk partitions]

[image: Failed to detect the free space]

If I try to do the Manual partition, the Debian installer detects my disk but it shows neither the Windows partition nor the unallocated free space (see third picture).

[image: Manual partitioning]

My Asus Zenbook Flip 15 is operating in UEFI BIOS mode, and my disk is an Intel Optane H10 with SSD 512GB. Checking my disk, I found that it is a basic disk (not dynamic disk) with a GPT partition style. Additionaly, the Fast boot and the Secure boot are disabled as recommened to install debian alongside Windows.

I am new installing linux so I don't know how to solve it. I have found similar problems in different forums on the web. However, the solutions they propose are related to having a dynamic memory, a MBR partition style, or using the Legacy boot mode instead of the UEFI mode. I have also disabled the VMD controller to change the SATA mode operation from RAID/RST to AHCI, but by doing this the Debian installer doesn't detect my disk at all.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or knows how to resolve it, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Additionally, any suggestions for troubleshooting steps would be welcome.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

EDITED:

Debian installer detects free space on the USB drive but not on my laptop drive if Windows fast start is disabled (see picture).

[image]

Comment: Do you have Windows fast start up on? That sets hibernation flag, preventing the NTFS partitions from being correctly seen? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436555/grub-cannot-boot-windows-error-not-a-valid-root-device

Comment: I disabled Windows fast start up as you suggested, but the Debian installer only detects free space on the USB drive. I edited the original post to include a picture showing this change.

Comment: Several models of Asus with Optane required Optane to be disabled. Some have then used the second NVMe drive as / ( but now with snaps even 30GB is not large.  I use Kubuntu and prevent snaps from installing and have used 14GB of my 30GB /. But Ubuntu with snaps would need more. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane Intel has obsoleted Optane. Some just add another NVMe drive.

Comment: I read from the links you provided that I have to switch the SATA mode from Intel Optane to AHCI. However, in my BIOS menu, I don't have any option to change this. I found a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL73D_m2Y3o&t) explaining that disabling the VMD controller switches the SATA Mode Operation from RAID/RST to AHCI. 

I disabled the VMD controller, but when I restarted my laptop, Windows couldn't boot, and the Debian Installer couldn't detect my laptop drive. Based on your links, I assume I don't have any AHCI or NVMe drivers, right?

Comment: Windows typically requires you to install a AHCI driver to boot it in AHCI  mode. I have a Dell with 11th Gen Intel and only one NVMe drive. I was surprised it installed using Kubuntu &  VMD driver. I actually forgot to change to AHCI as I have suggested to others many times. Some have posted they just removed the Optane card and replaced with standard NVMe drive. Asus Zenbook UX425EA w/Intel Iris Xe Graphics - turn off optane with Windows Optane app
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373
removal (setuprst.exe and setupoptanememory.exe - both from Dell

Comment: Following the link that you provided (and a link inside this link, and a link inside this new link, and so on), I found that a guy [solved this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1782946/i-cannot-find-disk-partition-on-ubuntu-installation-page-screenshot-attached-i/1783244#1783244) by disabling Intel Optane Memory using the Intel® Optane™ Memory and Storage Management app. Do you know if Windows will be able to boot after disabling Intel Optane Memory? I've been searching for an answer but it isn't clear if Windows will keep booting after disabling optane using this app.

Comment: All I know is that Windows has used the Optane memory for cache or fast startup. That is  a partial hibernation of just the boot files. Optane was typically sized to the max size of RAM. It was not used for anything else. Just make sure fast startup & hibernation are off, then Optane should not be used. Or a "cold" boot from full power down. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation And make sure you have AHCI driver installed.

Comment: After disabling Intel Optane Memory, the Debian Installer recognized my Windows partition and the unallocated space. Now I have both Windows 10 and Debian 12.4.0 on my Asus Zenbook Flip 15 (UX564). Thank you for your consistent help oldfred. I will write and answer with the recomendations I followed to be able to install Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last, I was finally able to install Debian 12.4.0 alongside Windows 10 on my Asus Zenbook Flip 15 (UX564). Below I list the recommendations I followed:

- Disable Fast boot.
- Disable Secure boot.
- Disable Windows fast start.
- Disable Intel Optane Memory using the [Intel® Optane™ Memory and Storage Management app](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000024626/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html).

After applying this configurations, the Debian installer can recognize my Windows partition and the unallocated space in the drive.